# "Jmdm zur Kenntnis gelangen" vs. "Jmdm zur Kenntnis bringen"

Tags: grammar, phrase

> Dieses Ökonomieproblem wurde dem Präsidenten zur Kenntnis gelangt.
>
> Dem Präsident hat das Ökonomieproblem zur Kenntnis gebracht.

What is the difference between the two phrases? Can they be interchangeable?

Comment: Neither sentence has a meaning. Since we do not know what the intended meaning is, we cannot correct them.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz To be even more picky: An ungrammatical sequence of words is not even a sentence ...

Comment: I guess you confused the two meanings: The first sentence should be with *gebracht* and the second with *ist ... gelangt*. And even then it does not make too much sense. But you should really be able to deduce that from translations in a [dictionary](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=zur%20Kenntnis%20bringen&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just focus on the two verbs in this answer.

You cannot

> jmdm zur Kenntnis gelangen.

"Gelangen" means "to reach" or to "make it to a place" and you can only do it. You cannot do it to someone.

> I reach you to Berlin... nope

Also, Kenntnis isn't used in combination with "gelangen" simply because people chose not to (no deeper reason). But you can attain it.

> Ich erlange Kenntnis von...

"Gelangen" works with "Erkenntnis" which means "Insight"

> Ich gelange zu der Erkenntnis, dass...

So... "Erkenntnis" is something you can go to in an abstract sense, and that works for "bringen" too

> Ich bringe dich zu der Erkenntnis...

With "Kenntnis" it is different again. It can mean knowledge you acquire but also the entirety of the knowledge you already have... kind of.

> Ich bringe/gebe dir zur Kenntnis, dass...
>
> I give/bring to your knowledge, that ... (lit.)

And then there is also this phrasing

> Ich setze dich in Kenntnis über...

So... these phrasings work but you cannot exchange parts because they are all fixed idioms that people have grown accustomed to.

Answer (score 4):

First of all both sentences unfortunately are incorrect. In addition to that they are not of a very high style.

```
Durch dieses Ökonomieproblem ist der Präsident zur Kenntnis gelangt.
```

This Version for example is correct. However, Kenntnis refers to knowledge. You would rather use Erkenntnis (insight) here because I assume that the president got an insight to an economical process due to the problem. That just as an example.

Furthermore there are different things to consider.

```
Der Präsident hat Kenntnis von dem Ökonomieproblem.
```

This would mean that the President is informed about the problem. He HAS "Kenntnis".

```
Der Präsident wurde über das Problem in Kenntnis gesetzt.
```

Someone informed the president and gave him insights concerning the problem.

You see that the way you use different verbs in this case can completely change the meaning. However, if you want to say that the president got insights about a certain problem you now have a few examples.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you tell me how the two phrases are used?

Comment: Those that I wrote down or those that you have in your question?

Comment: I wanted to know how to use "jmdm zur Kenntnis bringen" and "jmdm zur Kenntnis gelangen"

Comment: I think it should be either "zu dieser Kentniss" or "zur Kenntnis vün/über/, dass". "Zur Kenntnis" allein am Satzende klingt als ob was fehlt, da der bestimmte Artikel im Verbund mit "zu" alle seine hinweisende Kraft verliert. Das nachfolgende Objekt muss also spezifizert werden, es sei denn, es ist ein Allgemeinplatz wie U-Bahn.. ops.. mix Deutsch English.. sorry :)

Comment: I would not say that *Durch dieses Ökonomieproblem ist der Präsident zur Kenntnis gelangt.* is correct! Is should either be "Dieses Ökonomieproblem ist dem Präsidenten zur Kenntnis gelangt* (he was told about it), or *Durch dieses ... ist der Präsident zu der **Erkenntnis** gelangt, dass ...* (through the problem he realized,  that ...).